# Trouble connecting/configuring USART on STM32F072RBT6

Tags: serial-port, arm, stm32, usart

I am trying to connect my STM32F072RBT6 module to pc and send data through USART. I'm pretty new to this and I dont understand few things. Unfornately there are no examples available for this module. I use usb cable to connect stm with pc. Here is my code:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

void send_char(char c)
{
while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART2, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
USART_SendData(USART2, c);
}

void send_string(const char* s) 
{
while (*s)
    send_char(*s++);
}

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
int main(void)
{
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);

GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStruct);
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
//GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource2,GPIO_AF_1);  //tried this too


GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
//GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource3,GPIO_AF_1);
```

I read that Rx pin needs to be configured as floating input, but there is no 
mode like this to set. I also tried using GPIO_Mode_AF and commented PinAFConfig.

```
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
USART_StructInit(&USART_InitStructure);
USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 9600;              
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl=USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;   
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode=USART_Mode_Rx|USART_Mode_Tx;     
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity=USART_Parity_No;               
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits=USART_StopBits_1;            
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength=USART_WordLength_8b;       
USART_Init(USART2, &USART_InitStructure);

USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);

while (1) {
    send_string("Hello world!\r\n");
}
```

}

I am trying to see any results in teraterm. I noticed that when i accidentially touched pins od board, some characters appeared on terminal. Is that a sign that connection works but i have configured something wrong?
I also tried to do this with USART1 and it's pins but nothing happened. Can You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are examples

e.g. in [STM32CubeF0](http://www.st.com/stm32cubef0-pr) under `Projects/STM32F072RB-Nucleo/Examples/UART`

Though they use USART1, so you have to adapt them a bit.

### If there were no examples

then you could simply generate one using [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/microxplorer). Start a project with your MCU, click on the triangle next to USART2 (on the left), select Mode Asynchronous, then use Project / Generate Code, and there it is.